# iTunes Connect - Test Flight invitation not sending for internal testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, testflight

[image][image]I uploaded build to iTunesCOnnect for internal testing purpose.

Every time We upload build afater processing and providing export compliance we are able to see build for testing in Test flight app. Currently its not sending invitaions why?

Someone please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Exact same issue here. It used to work beginning of february and now it does not!

Comment: @Jordan,

Thanks for respond.

have you followed any steps to resolve. 

Please share me.

Comment: Same here. Seems like a bug in TestFlight

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue has started recently , you can make changes to Info.plist to get it working

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>  
<false/>
```

Please find detailed info at [complying_with_encryption_export_regulations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations)